# Bash Script loops endlessly under certain circumstances

Tags: linux, bash, wget

I am currently playing around with bash and did some scripting in the last days. I thought, that I'm done, but after some tests, it seems, that when it comes to a simple yes/no question that requires user interaction, it loops. The strange thing is, that it does not loop, whenever I run the script. It depends on how I run it. So here's an example script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while true; do
    read -rp " test? (y/n): " yn

    case $yn in
    [Yy]*)
        FOO="y"
        break
        ;;
    [Nn]*)
        FOO="n"
        break
        ;;
    *)
        echo -e " Please answer yes or no."
        echo ""
        ;;
    esac
done

echo "You picked $FOO"
```

As you can see, it doesn't do anything special. It asks for yes or no and displays a message if you type anything else. If I run it (on a Debian/Ubuntu machine) like this:

```sh
bash foo.sh
```

or like this:

```sh
chmod 755 foo.sh && ./foo.sh
```

or even like this (same script, hosted on GitHub Gist):

```sh
bash <(wget -qO- git.io/JUGDp)
```

it works as expected. But if I run it like this, it loops:

```sh
wget -qO- git.io/JUGDp | bash
```

I have a basic idea of why this happens, but even if my assumptions are correct, how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append `</dev/tty` to your `read` command to force reading from `tty` and not from `stdin`.

Answer (score 5):

When you run Bash at the end of a pipeline, its standard input is connected to the pipe; therefore `read` will not be able to read from the terminal.